# Cordova camera plugin not launching camera

Tags: cordova, camera, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I've created an Ionic app and I need the camera functionality so that a user can take a picture and send it to a webservice. I've followed the [following guide](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/cordova-camera/) by Ionic.

Basically you just `cd` into your applicatoin

```
cd myApp
```

then you run

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera
```

and once the plugin has been installed, you can invoke it's functionality where ever in your app (because according to Cordova, `navigator.camera` is a global object). In my case I'm just doing it in one of my controllers where the following function gets called after a button click using `ng-click` :

```
$scope.takePhoto = function() {

      navigator.camera.getPicture(function(imageURI) {

        // imageURI is the URL of the image that we can use for
        // an <img> element or backgroundImage.

      }, function(err) {

        // Ruh-roh, something bad happened


      }, cameraOptions);

    }
```

But it does nothing.. Now I've followed what Ionic said I must do to a 'T' and nothing more. Is there anything else I should be doing? Editing the `config.xml` perhaps? It's probably worth mentioning that this is the first time I've attempted in using a Cordova plugin of any sort.

Comment: Okay so the issue was that 'cameraOptions' was null. You either have to define some camera options or just leave that argument out completely.

Comment: Below code works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just resolved this problem by using below code,

```
$scope.takePhoto = function() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
        quality: 75,
        targetWidth: 320,
        targetHeight: 320,
        destinationType: 0
    });
   function onSuccess(imageData) {
         alert('onSuccess');
         console.log("data:image/jpeg;base64,"+imageData);
    }

    function onFail(message) {
        alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }
};
```

The **imageData** is the src of your captured image

Comment: Great thanks Muhsin, your code will work because you're actually providing the camera options. Mine failed because my 'cameraOptions' was null. Alternatively you could take those camera options out completely and it'll still work.