# program exits in opening image from $cordovaCamera.getPicture function in ionic app

Tags: camera, ionic-framework

can any one tell me what i am doing wrong here in my code ,where i am calling cordova.getPicture function ,first time when i open the app and start the camera in my app and click then app automaticaly  terminates with an error.

But second time when i open the app then its ok and displayed inside my app please help me out

```
 $scope.browse_logo=function($event) {
         var uploadPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
        title: "Upload Ad picture",
        templateUrl: 'templates/explore1.html',
        buttons: [
            {
                text: '',
                type: 'button button-icon icon ion-ios-camera',
                onTap: function(e) {

                  document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {

    var options = {
      quality: 75,
      destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      allowEdit: true,
      encodingType: 0,
      targetWidth: 320,
      targetHeight: 320,
    //  popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
      correctOrientation:true
    };

    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
  //    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
      $scope.logoPhoto = imageData;
    }, function(err) {
      // error
    });

  }, false);
         }
            },
            {
                text: 'From gallery',
                type: 'button button-positive',
                onTap: function(e) {
                  //  e.preventDefault();
               //     alert('Getting gallery');
                     $cordovaCamera.getPicture({
                        quality: 75,

        targetWidth: 320,
        targetHeight: 320,
     allowEdit: true,
        encodingType: 0,
       destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                        sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM
                    }).then(function(imageURI) {
                        //alert(imageURI);
                        $scope.logoPhoto = imageURI;


                    }, function(err) {
                        alert(err);
                    });
                }
            }
        ]
    });

 };
```

Comment: please try this,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32226318/cordova-camera-plugin-not-launching-camera/32227912#32227912

Comment: Thanks Mushin  ,but still exiting the program while adding image some times.and xiami mobile its not even working for atleast once.remaining devices its working but some times app closes abruptly